# Problem with JSON.stringify a tag outerHTML in multidimensional array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I'm trying to stringify a multidimensional array with some string and the outerHTML of an anchor tag. For some unknown (to me) reason, it adds a double `\` to the outerHTML text resulting in invalid JSON.

```js
const a = document.getElementByTagName('a')[0].outerHTML;
const array = [["a", a],["b", a],["c", a]];
const json = JSON.stringify(array);
```

The result is:

```js
'[["a","<a href=\\"https://www.google.com/\\" target=\\"_blank\\" rel=\\"noopener noreferrer\\">Link</a>"], 
["b","<a href=\\"https://www.google.com/\\" target=\\"_blank\\" rel=\\"noopener noreferrer\\">Link</a>"], 
["c","<a href=\\"https://www.google.com/\\" target=\\"_blank\\" rel=\\"noopener noreferrer\\">Link</a>"]]'
```

Comment: you copied this from console serialization.

Comment: you need to console.log it

Comment: @GottZ yes!!!!!

Comment: @GottZ go ahead and answer so I can accept it!

Comment: done. answer created. glad I could help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to `console.log` it

from experience, I can tell that you just copied this string from your dev console, after letting it debug-print the contents of that JSON Serialization.